# Validating a password with c++ and giving specific errors

Tags: c++, validation, passwords

I am trying to write a c++ program that validates a password that requires one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, and a digit using functions.

The issue is that I'm trying to display the specific errors that are occurring, not just "Invalid, try again.", but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do that. It should keep asking until they enter a valid password.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cctype>

using namespace std;

int validate(string);
string find(int);

int main()
{
    string pw;
    int val;
    string result;


    do{
            cout << "Enter password: " << endl;
            cin >> pw;
            val = validate(pw);
            cout << find(val) << endl;

      } while (val != 0);


}
//VALIDATES PASSWORD
int validate(string pw)
{
    int valid = 0;
    char c;
    int length = pw.length();
    bool digit = false;
    bool upper = false;
    bool lower = false;

    int i = 0;

    if (pw.length() < 6)
        valid = 1;

    while (i < pw.length())
    {
        c = pw[i];
        i++;

        if (isdigit(c))
        {
            digit = true;
            valid++;
        }
        if (isupper(c))
        {
            upper = true;
            valid++;
        }
        if (islower(c))
        {
            lower = true;
            valid++;
        }

        //Valid input
        if (length >= 6 && upper && lower && digit)
            valid = 0;

}

return valid;


}
//RETURNS STRING WITH PROBLEM
string find(int valid)
{

    string result;

    if (valid == 0)
    {
        result = "Valid Password ";
    }
    else
    {
        result = "Invalid Password: ";

        if (valid == 1)
            result = result + " Too short ";
        else if (valid == 2)
            result = result + " too short, needs a digit, and an uppercase letter";
        else if (valid == 3)
            result = result + " too short, needs a digit, and a lowercase letter";
        else if (valid == 4)
            result = result + " too short, and needs an uppercase letter";
        else if (valid == 5)
            result = result + " too short, and needs a lowercase letter";
        else if (valid == 6)
            result = result + " too short, needs a digit";


        else if (valid == 7)
            result = result + " Needs a didgit ";
        else if (valid == 8)
            result = result + " Needs digit and uppercase letter ";
        else if (valid == 9)
            result = result + " Needs digit and lowercase letter";


        else if (valid == 10)
            result = result + " Needs an uppercase letter ";
        else if (valid == 11)
            result = result + " Needs uppercase and lowercase letter";

        else if (valid == 12)
            result = result + " Needs a lowercase letter";

    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: google a bit about stringstreams ;)

Comment: Please try to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Why is `valid==1` an invalid password? That's just confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the number of characters (valid) and the type of error -

```
else if (valid == 9) 
    result = result + " Needs digit and lowercase letter";
```

could be produced from 123456abc

As `valid == 9` really only counts the characters in the set.  Separate counting and whether character classes are used.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use some flags (bool variables) instead of one number.
If you want to use one number, you must create 2^(things to check) situations
using that number. Here 2^4 = 16 situations is required.

One of the easiest way to mix flags in one number is this:
nth digit = nth flag

for example use this order (length, lower, upper, digit).
So,

```
to set length validity, add 1000 to number;
to set lower validity, add 100 to number;
to set upper validity, add 10 to number;
to set digit validity, add 1 to number;
```

Now,

```
((number)%10 == 1)  means digit validity
((number/10)%10 == 1)  means upper validity
((number/100)%10 == 1)  means lower validity
((number/1000)%10 == 1)  means length validity
```

Following code uses separate flags:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class PasswordStatus
{
    bool len, low, up, dig;
    //============
public:
    PasswordStatus()
    {
        len = low = up = dig = false;
    }
    //-----------
    void ShowStatus()
    {
        cout << endl << "Password Status:" << endl;
        cout << "Length : " << (len ? "OK" : "Too Short") << endl;
        cout << "Contains Lower Case : " << (low ? "Yes" : "No") << endl;
        cout << "Contains Upper Case : " << (up ? "Yes" : "No") << endl;
        cout << "Contains Digit : " << (dig ? "Yes" : "No") << endl;
    }
    //-----------
    void checkValidity(string pass)
    {
        int sLen = pass.length();

        len = (sLen >= 6);

        for(int i = 0; i<sLen; i++)
        {
            char c = pass[i];

            if(!low && islower(c)) {low = true; continue;}
            if(!up && isupper(c)) {up = true; continue;}
            if(!dig && isdigit(c)) {dig = true; continue;}
        }
    }
    //-----------
    bool IsTotalyValid()
    {
        return low && up && dig && len;
    }
};
//====================================================================
int main()
{
    PasswordStatus ps;
    string pw;

    do
    {
        cout << endl << "Enter password: " << endl;

        cin >> pw;

        ps.checkValidity(pw);
        ps.ShowStatus();
    } while (!ps.IsTotalyValid());

    cout << "Valid Password : " << pw;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd document that code and explain what you changed and why. Pure code answers tend to lead to [Cargo Cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) worship rather than learning.